# Python - Convert recursively to string in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, amazon-dynamodb

I have a list of dictionaries and in dictionaries there are mix data types, i.e. str, int, float, dict, list, etc. So, I want to make sure every item in dict at every depth is converted to string if it's not int or str, i.e. I want it to be put in DynamoDB. Here's the code I have been trying:

```
  def to_map(data):
    if(type(data) == list):
        for item in data:
            to_map(item)


    if type(data) == dict:    
        for attr in data:
            to_map(data[attr])

    if (type(data) != str) and (type(data) != int):
        return str(data) 

    return data
```

Comment: And what's wrong with your code?

Comment: It doesn't convert None, True, False to str, i.e. it returns same thing.

Comment: Give example of your data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you loop on a dictionary, you only get keys, not values as well. Additionally, since `str(my_str) == my_str`, you don't need to check if a value is a str before converting it. Also, use `isinstance` instead of `type(x) == ?`. Are you looking for something like this?

```
def to_map(data):
    if isinstance(data, list):
        return [to_map(x) for x in data]
    elif isinstance(data, dict):
        return {to_map(key): to_map(val) for key, val in data.items()}
    elif isinstance(data, int) and not isinstance(data, bool):
        return data
    else:
        return str(data)
```

Comment: This works, except it doesn't convert `bool` to `str`. Trying to add condition for `bool` as well.

Comment: Huh, fascinating. I never knew that `bool` is a subtype of `int`, thanks for that little discovery of the day. Updated the answer to handle this particular case.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that either :) But, that worked, thanks!

Comment: This seems to work without `and not isinstance(data, bool):` `to_map(False)` outputs 
`False`

Comment: @Prateek that's the problem, OP wants `to_map(False)` to output `"False"` instead of `False`

Comment: oh..ok..I used `print` and call function both gave `False` I thought that was `"False"`

Answer (score 1):

I assume when you mean "every depth", you wish to still traverse any `dict`s or `list`s to reach the next level. To do so, you can check the type in a comprehension with recursion. Then, the function can be mapped over your list of dictionaries:

```
def convert(structure, lookup = {int:str, float:str, bool:str, set:str, str:str}):
   return {lookup[type(a)](a):lookup.get(type(b), convert)(b) for a, b in structure.items()}

data = [{"val1":100, "val3":True, 200:{"val2":{200:{"new_depth":{"last_val":23.233, "second_last":"new_str"}}}}}]
last_result = list(map(convert, data))
```

Output:

```
[{'val3': 'True', '200': {'val2': {'200': {'new_depth': {'last_val': '23.233', 'second_last': 'new_str'}}}}, 'val1': '100'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This converts all values to str except for ints if possible as requested:

```
def to_map(iterable):
    if type(iterable) == list:
        return [str(item) if (type(item) not in [dict,str,list,int]) else to_map(item) for item in iterable ]
    elif type(iterable) == dict:
        return dict([[item,str(iterable[item])] if type(iterable[item]) not in [dict,str,list,int] else [item,to_map(iterable[item])] for item in iterable])
    elif type(iterable) == int:
        return iterable
x = {'1':2,'2':{'5':6,'6': False,'7':[1,2,3,4.55454]}}

print(to_map(x))
>> {'1': 2, '2': {'5': 6, '6': 'False', '7': [1, 2, 3, '4.55454']}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the `json` package and `json.dumps` your dictionary. That will create a json string with your dictionary that you can store in dynamoDB as a JSON document or directly as a string if you are so inclined. In this case you can later read it and `json.loads` it back into a python dictionary.

Using JSON also means you'll have less compatibility problems in the future if you need to interface with other products or applications.

Comment: I did that previously, but what happens when there are thousands of dictionaries in a list? How long will the sting be if we dump that list of dictionaries?

Comment: you dump each dict in the list separately, so you get a list of json strings. In any case it will be as large as your original list of dictionaries, why would it be longer?